# Use python with threading as service in Linux

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, service, multiprocessing

I create a python code like below:

```
base_func() #start this function once
t1 = threading.Thread(target=loop_func_1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=loop_func_2)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
#both threads (t1 and t2) having unlimited while inside them
```

`loop_func_1` also include python multiprocessing

I try to create Linux service file like below:

```
[Unit]
Description = my code description
After = network.target
 
[Service]
Type = simple
WorkingDirectory = /home/script_location/
ExecStart = /usr/bin/python3 /home/scrip_file_location.py
Restart = on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

After I start the service there is no error and the service has been activated, but the script not working

I check status with the command below:

```
sudo systemctl status myservicename
```

Comment: how do you know it is not working? what do `loop_func_`s even do?

Comment: @Matiiss because it has a unix socket and after I sent data to socket the socket don't send any response